# Вывод из массива js

Tags: javascript

В массиве 15 имен. Как вывести циклом for c седьмого по десятое имя.Спасибо

Comment: Именно в цикле? Переменной счетчика присвоить значение  `let i = 6` и условие определить, как `i < 10`.

Comment: Вроде так?    for (i = 8; i < 10; i++) {
    text += arr[i] + "<br>";

Comment: Разве я где-то упоминал про `8`?

Comment: спутал -6 . Спасибо

Comment: Не за что. Не забывайте заглядывать на [нужные ресурсы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) и вопросы такого плана будете легко решать сами. И не забудьте оживить в памяти, всё что [связано с Массивами](https://learn.javascript.ru/array) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'];

arr.slice(6, 10).forEach(i => console.log(i));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var letters = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'jj', 'kk'];

let r = letters.filter(function(el, ind) {
  return (ind > 2 && ind < 4);
});

alert(r);
```